# How to fix unknown and cache errors when working with the GodotFirebase plugin

Tags: firebase, plugins, godot, gdscript

I’ve been working with the GodotFirebase plug-in and it’s been working perfectly until earlier today when it randomly started throwing errors.

[Firebase Error] >> Error saving cache file! Error code: 3
[Firebase Error] >> Error updating cache file! Error code: 3

[Firebase Error] >> Unknown error

I think: the unknown error comes when I try and update a document, the cache error comes when I try and add a document.

I’ve tried going through the plug-in script and printing things to help me but I can’t workout what any of it means. The weird part is that it was working fine and suddenly stopped (maybe this means it’s not a problem with my Godot scripts??). Thanks in advance